# GNUStep Getting Started

Tags: ide, gnustep

I downloaded [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) and installed it, however I am not sure where I can find an IDE. does anyone know what programs serve as a GNUStep IDE/where to get them? Failing that, does anyone know of a tutorial on how to create and compile a basic GNUStep program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my experiences with that are devastating. ProjectCenter the IDE distributed for GNUstep does not work here at all the debugger intergration is well not existant. But that's what you get with GNUstep. There is Gorm as interface builder and ProjectCenter. Not more. That's very discouraging. The best you can do with Objective-C is currently having a Mac in some form and use XCode. That's the best you can get currently, and I expect that won't change in any forseeable future.

Now you should step back and just use the "plain" old Makefile route. There is a somewhat very rough tutorial about GNUStep makefile starting somewhere below
http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/User_Guides

Regards
Friedrich

Answer (score 1):

As Friedrich already mentions in [his post above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060958/gnustep-getting-started/1096323#1096323) there is Gorm for creating interfaces and ProjectCenter as IDE (gdb integration is worked on as far as I know).

For compiling GNUstep programs you are best of using GNUstep-make. You can find some recently updated tutorials here:

[Basic GNUstep-make tutorial](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/)

[More advanced GNUstep-make tutorial](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/MoreOnMakefiles/)

And there is always the whole bunch of [newsgroups, irc and mailinglists](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Get_Help) where you can usually get quick answers to your questions. Maybe not on IRC currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make eclipse
work with gnustep/msys/mingw:

http://wirecode.blogspot.com/2007/11/objective-c-and-eclipse.html
http://djsilenceboy.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/install-minggw-and-gnustep-for-ccobj-c-for-windows/