# Objective-c compiling issues... help?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

Please forgive me since this question i am also sure, has been asked before i expect. 
The problem i am having is that i am trying to learn obj-c on a pc seeing as i do not have a mac yet. i am using Jedit to write my code and GNUstep to compile and create. however my problem is occurring when trying to compile using the #include

according to the book i am using to learn as well as everything else i have found online (and do not quite understand), i need either a make file or point my compiler at a library or directory. i would prefer the make file i suppose as it seems a lot easier and faster to test things and learn.

the main question then is this: i seem to have found a GNUmake file that came with the online additions to my book, but i do not know how to use it or where to go with it. so if some one can please point out for me a easy to understand process or knows of such process and would be willing to impart that wisdom, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you kindly for your time

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of this question, but keep in mind that you don't have Cocoa, Carbon, or CoreAnything.

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Perhaps this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060958/gnustep-getting-started

Comment: Tag this question with gnustep if you want more help by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have installed GNUstep correctly and your environment is set up (all explained in the documentation) then you actually need to create a blank GNUmakefile in the root directory of your project and list your sources in that.

Here's a simple "Hello World" command line example:

Create a directory to contain your source code.  HelloWorld would be a good idea.

In that, create files `main.m`, `Greeter.m` and `Greeter.h`.

We'll create the `Greeter` class which will just have one method `-sayHelloToRecipient:`.

In the `Greeter.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Greeter : NSObject {
}

-(void)sayHelloToRecipient:(NSString *)recipientName;

@end
```

And in the `Greeter.m`:

```
#import "Greeter.h"

@implementation Greeter

-(void)sayHelloToRecipient:(NSString *)recipientName {
    NSLog(@"Hello %@!", recipientName);
}

@end
```

Your `main.m` file simply includes the `Greeter` and invokes it with the argument `@"World"`.

```
#import "Greeter.h"

int main(void) {
    Greeter *greeter = [[Greeter alloc] init];
    [greeter sayHelloToRecipient:@"World"];
    [greeter release];
    return 0;
}
```

Now you've got your sources ready to build, you just need to *create* a `GNUmakefile`.  Make an empty file, and start it with the line: `include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make`, ending with the line `include $(GNUSTPEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make`.

The first line includes all the other makefiles and targets GNUstep provides.  The last line includes the makefiles needed to produce a command line tool.  If you were build a GUI app you'd include `application.make`.  For frameworks you'd include `framework.make` etc.

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

# Your project-specific directives will go here

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

The stuff you put between these lines is the stuff that changes from project to project.

The complete `GNUmakefile` looks like this:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

HELLO_ROOT_DIR = $(abspath .)

GNUSTEP_BUILD_DIR = $(HELLO_ROOT_DIR)/build

TOOL_NAME = HelloWorld

HelloWorld_OBJC_FILES = \
    Greeter.m \
    main.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

`HELLO_ROOT_DIR` is entirely optional and is just a variable that saves me from having to re-type the path to the root as the project grows (and so does the complexity of the makefile).

`TOOL_NAME` is required for a command line tool and specifies both the output filename, and determines what you need to use for the `*_OBJC_FILES` line (i.e. in this case I need to use `HelloWorld_OBJC_FILES` because `TOOL_NAME` is "HelloWorld".

With this in place, provided you're in the same directory as the makefile, you should be able to just type `make' to build the tool.  It will create a "build" directory and inside that you'll find the executable.  This one when invoked just outputs:

```
-$  ./build/obj/HelloWorld 
2010-11-28 03:36:28.459 HelloWorld[12949] Hello World!
```

None of this will work however if your environment is not configured correctly.  I've never done this on Windows, but I assume the same principles apply.  That's running a shell script on Linux/UNIX (running batch file on Windows?) in order to configure the environment.

```
-$  . /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
```

You can check if it's correctly configured by printing the environment variable `GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES` to the console:

```
-$  echo $GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES
```

(Not sure how you do this on Windows)

If it outputs nothing, your environment is not correctly configured and/or GNUstep is not correctly installed.  If it outputs a path, you should be safe to run `make'.

Comment: You know, you may find developing with GNUstep to be a more enjoyable experience if you install VirtualBox and create a Linux virtual machine to run it on.  I can imagine there being a lot of non-standard ways to do things on Windows that will complicate the learning process for you.